# Environment Aligning Two Inner Environments

Tags: horizontal-alignment, environments

I am trying to create an environment allows for displaying two environments side by side. These two environments are `\code` environments. A `\code` environment allows for a title for the code to be passed as well as the code itself.

The solution I have come up with is using a minipage around the first environment and another minipage around the second environment. Now, instead of doing all of this work over and over again, I would like to define a new environment that allows for two titles to be passed as well as the codes. Perhaps something like this: `\compare{title 1}{title 2}{code 1}{code 2}`

How can this be achieved? Thank you in advance.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{code}[1][]{%
    \@totalleftmargin=0pt%
    \def\foot{#1} 
    \tcbwritetemp}%
    {\endtcbwritetemp%
    \ifx\foot\@empty
    \tcbox[before = \begin{center}, after = \end{center},
    fonttitle = \color{white}\itshape\ttfamily, colframe = blue, 
    listing only, listing options = {language = c++}
    ]%
    {\tcbusetemplisting}%
    \else
    \tcbox[title = {\foot}, % The title option is present here
    before = \begin{center}, after = \end{center},
    fonttitle = \color{white}\itshape\ttfamily, colframe = blue, 
    listing only, listing options = {language = c++}
    ]%
    {\tcbusetemplisting}%
    \fi
}%
\makeatother

\lstset{
    frameround=fttt,
    language=c++,
    breaklines=true,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries, 
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{red},
    numberstyle=\color{black},
    keepspaces=true
    }

% DOESN'T WORK
\newenvironment{compare}[4]{
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{code}[#1]
#3
\begin{code}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{code}[#2]
#4
    \begin{code}
\end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}    
    Start a list:
    \begin{enumerate}[label = \textbf{--}]
        \item The first item:\\
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{code}[title1]
xx
            \end{code}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{code}[title2]
yy
            \end{code}
        \end{minipage}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Instead of doing all the above, I want to have something like the following:
    %\compare[title 1][title 2]{int x = 0;}{int y = 1;}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are mismatching `\begin{code}` and `\end{code}` in your “DOESN'T WORK“ `compare` environment and `\newenvironment` is missing an argument (if you wanted to use `\newcommand`, you should have used `\compare` instead of`compare`). But the biggest problem is that verbatim material can't be conveniently captured in arguments, as far as I know; environments are better for that.

Then comes a second hurdle: you want to capture two such things at the same time, using one environment—but an environment has only one contents... The solution I propose is to use two environments `listingA` and `listingB` inside the `compare` environment, that are only valid  there. These two environments store the verbatim text (code) in two different files which the `compare` environment can then read in order to display the code side by side, as you wish.

Notes:

- For the `equal height group` option of `tcolorbox` to do its full effect, two compilations are needed in general. This option ensures that side-by-side `listingA` and `listingB` (i.e., from the same `compare` environment call) have the same height.
- If you want to be able to start your listings with a `#` character, apparently ou have to give up on the fact that  the argument to `listingA` and `listingB` (the listing title) is optional, see below.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter

\lstset{
    frameround=fttt,
    language=c++,
    breaklines=true,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{red},
    numberstyle=\color{black},
    keepspaces=true
    }

\newtoks\titleListingA
\newtoks\titleListingB
% We need to define a new 'equal height group' every time the 'compare'
% environment is used, so that listings A and B in a given call of the
% 'compare' environment have the same height; but this height is not
% necessarily the same across several calls to the 'compare' environment. So,
% we'll use a name based on the number of times the 'compare' environment has
% been called in the document.
\newcounter{myCompareEnvCounter}

\newenvironment{listingA}[1][]{%
  \errmessage{Use of environment 'listingA' is invalid outside 'compare'}}{}

\newenvironment{listingB}[1][]{%
  \errmessage{Use of environment 'listingB' is invalid outside 'compare'}}{}

\newenvironment{compare}{%
  \renewenvironment{listingA}[1][]{%
    \global\titleListingA={##1}%
    \tcbverbatimwrite{\jobname_listingA.cxx}%
  }{\endtcbverbatimwrite\ignorespacesafterend}%
  %
  \renewenvironment{listingB}[1][]{%
    \global\titleListingB={##1}%
    \tcbverbatimwrite{\jobname_listingB.cxx}%
  }{\endtcbverbatimwrite\ignorespacesafterend}%
  \stepcounter{myCompareEnvCounter}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \unskip
  % Common options for the two boxes: expand the counter representation
  \edef\mytcbOptions{%
    \unexpanded{width=(\linewidth-4pt)/2,
      before=, after=\hfill,
      fonttitle = \color{white}\itshape\ttfamily, colframe = blue,
      listing only, listing options = {language = c++},
      equal height group=myCompareGroup-}\themyCompareEnvCounter}%
  \expandafter\tcbset\expandafter{\mytcbOptions}%
  \par\noindent
  %
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\@nil\the\titleListingA\@nil
    \tcbset{notitle}%
  \else
    \tcbset{adjusted title={\the\titleListingA}}%
  \fi
  \tcbinputlisting{listing file={\jobname_listingA.cxx}}%
  %
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\@nil\the\titleListingB\@nil
    \tcbset{notitle}%
  \else
    \tcbset{adjusted title={\the\titleListingB}}%
  \fi
  \tcbinputlisting{listing file={\jobname_listingB.cxx}}%
  %
  \renewenvironment{listingA}[1][]{%
    \errmessage{Use of environment 'listingA' is invalid outside 'compare'}}{}%
  %
  \renewenvironment{listingB}[1][]{%
    \errmessage{Use of environment 'listingB' is invalid outside 'compare'}}{}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
Start a list:
\begin{enumerate}[label = \textbf{--}]
\item The first item:
  \begin{compare}
    \begin{listingA}[\#verycool]
int a = 0;
    \end{listingA}
%
    \begin{listingB}[Second listing]
int b = 0;
    \end{listingB}
  \end{compare}

\item Other item:
  \begin{compare}
    \begin{listingA}            % no title here
// Comment here
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
    \end{listingA}
%
    \begin{listingB}[Some title]
int zzz = 12;
    \end{listingB}
  \end{compare}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the same code, but with the argument to `listingA` and `listingB`, i.e., the listing title, made mandatory (just use an empty or blank value if you want no title). This allows code listings to start with a `#` character, so is probably desirable. This version uses `etoolbox`'s `\ifblank` command to test whether the argument in question is blank (i.e., is empty or only contains space tokens).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter

\lstset{
    frameround=fttt,
    language=c++,
    breaklines=true,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{red},
    numberstyle=\color{black},
    keepspaces=true
    }

\newtoks\titleListingA
\newtoks\titleListingB
% We need to define a new 'equal height group' every time the 'compare'
% environment is used, so that listings A and B in a given call of the
% 'compare' environment have the same height; but this height is not
% necessarily the same across several calls to the 'compare' environment. So,
% we'll use a name based on the number of times the 'compare' environment has
% been called in the document.
\newcounter{myCompareEnvCounter}

\newenvironment{listingA}[1][]{%
  \errmessage{Use of environment 'listingA' is invalid outside 'compare'}}{}

\newenvironment{listingB}[1][]{%
  \errmessage{Use of environment 'listingB' is invalid outside 'compare'}}{}

\newenvironment{compare}{%
  \renewenvironment{listingA}[1]{%
    \global\titleListingA={##1}%
    \tcbverbatimwrite{\jobname_listingA.cxx}%
  }{\endtcbverbatimwrite\ignorespacesafterend}%
  %
  \renewenvironment{listingB}[1]{%
    \global\titleListingB={##1}%
    \tcbverbatimwrite{\jobname_listingB.cxx}%
  }{\endtcbverbatimwrite\ignorespacesafterend}%
  \stepcounter{myCompareEnvCounter}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \unskip
  % Common options for the two boxes: expand the counter representation
  \edef\mytcbOptions{%
    \unexpanded{width=(\linewidth-4pt)/2,
      before=, after=\hfill,
      fonttitle = \color{white}\itshape\ttfamily, colframe = blue,
      listing only, listing options = {language = c++},
      equal height group=myCompareGroup-}\themyCompareEnvCounter}%
  \expandafter\tcbset\expandafter{\mytcbOptions}%
  \par\noindent
  %
  \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\the\titleListingA}{%
    \tcbset{notitle}%
  }{%
    \tcbset{adjusted title={\the\titleListingA}}%
  }%
  \tcbinputlisting{listing file={\jobname_listingA.cxx}}%
  %
  \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\the\titleListingB}{%
    \tcbset{notitle}%
  }{%
    \tcbset{adjusted title={\the\titleListingB}}%
  }%
  \tcbinputlisting{listing file={\jobname_listingB.cxx}}%
  %
  \renewenvironment{listingA}[1][]{%
    \errmessage{Use of environment 'listingA' is invalid outside 'compare'}}{}%
  %
  \renewenvironment{listingB}[1][]{%
    \errmessage{Use of environment 'listingB' is invalid outside 'compare'}}{}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
Start a list:
\begin{enumerate}[label = \textbf{--}]
\item The first item:
  \begin{compare}
    \begin{listingA}{\#verycool}
int a = 0;
    \end{listingA}
%
    \begin{listingB}{Second listing}
int b = 0;
    \end{listingB}
  \end{compare}

\item Other item:
  \begin{compare}
    \begin{listingA}{}          % no title here
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
    \end{listingA}
%
    \begin{listingB}{Some title}
int zzz = 12;
    \end{listingB}
  \end{compare}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of second version]

Comment: Thank you! All good!