# Two listings side-by-side in TColorBox

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, listings, tcolorbox

I have two requests:

I am trying to compare two codes side by side using `tcolorbox`. The problem is that I am not able to put them both with code format (*i.e.,* one is in plaintext and the other is in code). I have specified `comment and listing, comment = {#3},` in the options but I don't know how to make them independent from each other using `listing only`.

The second request is to align both codes vertically to the top (you can see an extra empty line is present at the right side).

Thank you in advance!

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\lstdefinelanguage{myC++}{
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    language = c++
}

\lstdefinelanguage{myC++}{
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    language = c++
}

\lstset{language=myC++}

\newtcblisting[auto counter]{snippetbox}[3][]{
    after=\par\nointerlineskip,
    before=\par\nointerlineskip,
    enhanced,
    skin=bicolor,
    lower separated=true,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=#2,
    after title={\hfill Right code},
    comment and listing,
    comment = {#3},
    listing options={aboveskip=0pt,
    belowskip=0pt,
    language=myC++},
    sidebyside,
    sidebyside align=top,
    #1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item The first code snippet
        \begin{snippetbox}{left code}
{int x = 0;//this should also  be in code style.}
int x = 0;
    \end{snippetbox}
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Didn't you read the [answer to your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/493446/73317)? As I told you, I doubt you will manage to put a non-trivial listing in a macro or environment argument, as you are trying to do here with your argument containing `int x = 0;//this should also  be in code style.`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did see the answer (and thanks for it). Indeed, I feel that I might be missing something with regards to the `\tcolorbox` options as I specified `comment and listing` instead of `listing only`. I am not sure if there is a clever way around this. I will accept your answer in a few days btw.

Comment: Listing contents is special because it needs to ignore most TeX rules, as is the case with `verbatim`-like environments. These kinds of things are so bizarre for TeX that the only sane way to process them, AFAIK, is in the **contents of an environment**, not in a macro or environment argument. As an environment can have only **one** contents, you have to use two environments to grab two listings, that is what my [answer to your other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/493446/73317) does. You would like a `listing and listing` option, but it doesn't exist—probably for these very reasons.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback! I will simmer down for a little bit; *maybe* there is a clever way that deals with this.

Comment: All right. BTW, how would you include a code snippet that has one more closing brace than opening brace, in an argument (yes, one can construct something similar also with environments)?

Comment: Well the only way I can think about (I didn't test though) is using `escapeinside={...}` in the listings options. Then you might want to display \{ or \} in the same font as the listings.

Comment: Okay, maybe. I was thinking *without any escaping mechanism.* My “point” was that it seems like a somewhat stronger condition to require balanced `{` and `}` than it is to require balanced `\begin{listingA}` and `\end{listingA}`, for instance. But I admit this is not very very convincing. Never mind. I can delete my comments starting from “All right. BTW, how would you...” if you think they pollute the discussion more than they help. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following code shows an alternative for two listings side by side. Instead of using one `tcolorbox`, it builds a `tcbraster` with two independent tcblistings inside.

At the moment, the code construction is not optimal because you have to declare the raster and listings with an empty parameter inside. I hope someone else could do it but I don't know how to improve it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\lstdefinelanguage{myC++}{
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    language = c++
}

\lstdefinelanguage{myC++}{
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    language = c++
}

\lstset{language=myC++}

\tcbset{
    snippetraster/.style={
        enhanced,
        raster columns=2,
        raster equal height=rows,
%       raster before skip=0pt,
        raster after skip=0pt,
        raster left skip=0pt,
        raster right skip=0pt,
        raster column skip=0pt,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        listing only,
        listing options={aboveskip=0pt, belowskip=0pt, language=myC++},
        raster column 1/.style={
            sharp corners=east,
            title=Left code,
            before title=\strut,
            rightrule=0pt
        },
        raster column 2/.style={
            colback=black!20,
            sharp corners=west,
            title=Right code,
            before title=\strut\hfill,
            leftrule=0pt
        },      
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item The first code snippet
\begin{tcbraster}[snippetraster]
\begin{tcblisting}{}  %<- Empty parameter needed (I don't know why)
int x = 0; //this should also  be in code style.
\end{tcblisting}
\begin{tcblisting}{}
int x = 0;
\end{tcblisting}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The mandatory argument of the `tcblisting` environment is documented in the [`tcolorbox` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) (page 300 in the version I have here).

Comment: Note: you have duplicate `\lstdefinelanguage{myC++}{...}`.

Comment: Thank you! I worked as expected :)